# Импорт m2m связей в django-import-export

Tags: python, django, python-2.x

В панели управления использую приложение django-import-export.

Вот пример конфигурации для одной из моделей:

```
class ImportExportAdsTypeResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = AdType
        import_id_fields = ('name',)
        fields = ['name', 'active', 'position', 'categories', 'sites']
```

где `sites` и `categories` - m2m поля.

Экспорт проходит нормально, получаем, например, CSV файл со следующим содержанием:

```
name,active,position,sites,categories
Тест экспорт CSV,1,13,1,"19,26"
```

Но при попытке импорта m2m поля не добавляются. Как импортировать данные вместе с m2m связями?